# Searching for substrings using 'srtchr()'

Tags: c, string, substring, string-search, strchr

Using the function `strchr` is it possible to search for a *substring* in a string instead of a *character*?

**Example:**

Instead of this :

```
int r=strchr("Hello World",'W');
```

Can this be used :

```
int r=strchr("Hello World","World");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. You can use [`strstr`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm) for that

```
char *substring = strstr("Hello World","World");
```

Answer (score 3):

> Using the function 'strchr()' is it possible to search for a
>   'substring' in a string instead of a 'character'?
>
> **Example :**
>
> Instead of this : int r=strchr("Hello World",'W');
>
> Can this be used : int r=strchr("Hello World","World");

No, that's what [`strstr()` is for](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html).

Note also that [`strchr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) does not return `int`, it returns a `char *` pointer to the character searched for, or `NULL` if not found.  Compiler warnings exist for a reason...

Comment: Can strstr() be used with 'unsigned char' as well?

Comment: @nivedithanatarajan As long as both arguments passed are `'\0'`-terminated strings, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Use strstr for this.

Use this link for reference

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/